# How to excute code after Flask app (app.run) started

Tags: python, flask

Got a video steaming app in Flask (python) http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask running perfectly.

But I want to use a method that also saves all picture frames from the camera (which I have functional already).

The issue is, once I start the Flask App, I can at best only store the frames that are captured when I open the web page in localhost. I want to be able to execute other code (saving the pictures) while the app is running, so as to save all pictures and also display to localhost whenever I open the page on the browser.

What do I do to achieve these simultaneous tasks?

Flask app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
    #want to be able to run code while localhost webpage is closed
```

At the start index() is called once, then if I open the webpage at any time, video_feed() calls gen(). If I close the webpage, I get `error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine` and the .py file crashes, probably because I've stopped transmitting to a client. I need to be able to run code after the client has closed the connection and still have the app running for the next client.

I want to be able to execute code while the app is still running but no localhost web page has been opened. So someone opening the web page would be a sort of interrupt from the normal code, till the web page is closed.

Comment: You shouldn't have the infinite while loop trying to run the app instance. Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with what you have (minus the other code is missing)

Comment: The while loop loops only if I close out of the app (Ctrl-C). I want to be able to execute code while the app is still running but no localhost web page has been opened

Comment: And as I said, just like running code without flask, you can add more lines after you run the app... It sounds like your problem is the `gen(camera)` method

Comment: if I have app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001) then print 'a', the print 'a' doesn't execute until I Ctrl-C out of the app.run, which not what I want. I want code to run Simultaneously while app.run is also running, but no client has connected to my port yet.

Comment: Ah, right. Umm, maybe threading? Start a separate thread to run your "other" code?

Comment: Was hoping to avoid that because having the app running again for another client after I close the webpage is essential for me. Is there nothing better?

Comment: Other than running your code before `app.run`. not that I am aware of